# Is there a way to delete a scheduled task if you only know the filename of the application the task will run

Tags: batch-file, command-line, scheduled-tasks, findstr

I need to delete a scheduled task on a large number of machines preferably using only the command line. The problem is that the tasks were manually added on every computer, so the name of the task is not consistent between each one. I was hoping I could delete the task using the name of the exe file that the task runs, but this does not appear to be an option of the schtasks command.

I thought I was making progress using this command, but its not returning the name of the task for it to then be deleted.

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=\" %%x in ('schtasks /query /fo:list ^| findstr ^^PrintTask.exe') do schtasks /Delete /TN "%%x" /F
```

Comment: `schtasks` supports a `/V` switch…

Comment: List would be the wrong format.  You want to use CSV.

Comment: I did try using that too, but it hasnt helped me put tiogether a command to delete a task based on the program the task runs

Comment: If you don't know the taskname, then it's unlikely that you'll have the required permissions to delete that task. Could you please therefore provide more background as to what exactly you're trying to do and why. Providing a real example, with a genuine filename, and preferably showing us the exact output you're trying to parse would help. Currently giving us a `for` loop containing that command, when we have no idea what that command is outputting, serves no purpose. If the command you've shown within the parentheses does not expose the information you require, then we have no code to fix.